# Mudar tema do BootsFaces

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, java-ee, jsf, bootsfaces

Estou tentando mudar o tema de uma aplicação BootsFaces e não estou conseguindo. No site diz que tenho que encontrar uma pasta chamada `less` porem não consigo encontra-la.

> Customization of the BootsFaces.jar
>
> Until there is a new version of the customizer, you can still
>   customize the look and feel taking advantage of the build system.
>   There are many Bootstrap customizers on the net, for example
>   Bootswatch . What you need is a file with the variables to customize
>   the build. Some customizers will provide you a .less file as well.
>
> Put the files in the BootsFaces/less directory of the build and tweak
>   the bs-* files to use your variables / .less file.
>   http://www.bootsfaces.net/quickstart.jsf

Comment: Já tentou você mesmo criar a pasta pra ver se funciona?

Comment: Ainda nao, posso criar na raiz, bootsfaces/less ?

Comment: Tenta criar no local em que ele indica na documentacao.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar

Comment: Coloquei a pasta `BoostsFaces/less` no `webapp` e os arquivos `.less ` que baixei no `bootswatch` e não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De a cordo com o site para você customizar você vai ter que fazer a build pela source do `BootsFace`.
Segue o [link](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/tree/master/BootsFaces) do Github deles onde a pasta less está localizada.

Comment: Então se eu quiser customizar tenho que usar esse projeto como "Template"? fazer minha aplicação em cima dele?

Comment: Sim, você faz todas as modificações que quiser e depois faz a build para usar no seu projeto.

Comment: Como assim fazer a build pra usar no meu projeto? eu adiciono tudo em meu projeto ou faço meu projeto em cima desse modelo?

Comment: ele ensina a fazer o build no tópico 'Building the BootsFaces.jar from source'

Comment: Vou procurar, e tentar.